# Rename [c18] to [mplab-c18] (it's about a specific compiler, not an ISO standard)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

MPLAB C18 is a C compiler for PIC18 microcontrollers. The tag [c18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c18) has been around for a long while for this purpose.

When the C17/C18 version of the C language was released, we noticed this naming collision. It wasn't clear what to call this C version, because `__STDC_VERSION__` is `201710L` but the ISO standard is called ISO 9899:2018. We went with [c17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c17) for such questions.

I noticed that some people are using the C18 tag for questions about ISO 9899:2018, which is wrong. Therefore I propose that [c18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c18) should be renamed [mplab-c18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mplab-c18) which also happens to be the full, most correct name for that compiler.

Once this is done, I can volunteer to fix the 47 questions currently using the [c18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c18) tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done: the [c18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c18) tag has been renamed to [mplab-c18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mplab-c18). The [c18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c18) tag is no more (it will be automatically deleted as a "zombie tag" within 24 hours). I also made some trivial tweaks to the tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: Woah fixed in 3 minutes! Thanks Cody :) I'll start reviewing and cleaning up the mplab-c18 questions.

Comment: It's been cleaned up. It was only 10 or so questions that needed edits, since every old post with the tag was already about MPLAB.

Comment: It was easier than a colon cleanse. ;-) Thanks for cleaning up the edges.